# Excel Macro | 1 Column - Find a cell with text and copy/paste over cell starting with a number

Tags: excel, vba

I am very very new and self-taught on VBA macros in Excel.  I have found this site very helpful, but I am stumped on this one.

I am trying to figure out the best way to..

Start at the top of a column.
Find the first cell that does not begin with "08"
Copy that cell and paste down until there is another cell that does not begin with "08".
At that point, then copy the new cell and continue to paste down to repeat the pattern.

Below is a before/after so you can get a sense of what I am wanting to do. Thank you for any suggestions/help.

Before:

```
HEADER1
 08/01/2014
 08/02/2014
 08/04/2014
 08/05/2014
 08/06/2014
HEADER2
 08/01/2014
 08/02/2014
 08/04/2014
 08/05/2014
 08/06/2014
 08/07/2014
 08/08/2014
 08/09/2014
HEADER3
 08/11/2014
 08/13/2014
HEADER4
 08/25/2014
 08/26/2014
 08/27/2014

After:
HEADER1
HEADER1
HEADER1
HEADER1
HEADER1
HEADER1
HEADER2
HEADER2
HEADER2
HEADER2
HEADER2
HEADER2
HEADER2
HEADER2
HEADER2
HEADER3
HEADER3
HEADER3
HEADER4
HEADER4
HEADER4
HEADER4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code:

```
Sub FillDwn()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String
    
    Set startCell = Range("A1") 'Change to correct starting cell
    Set r = startCell
    
    For i = startCell.Row To startCell.Row + startCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
        str = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cells(i, startCell.Column))
        str = Left(str, 2)
        
        If str = "08" Then Cells(i, startCell.Column) = r.Value Else Set r = Cells(i, startCell.Column)
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Copy this into a module and run.  Make sure you update the range of `startCell`!

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply. The only problem seems to be the dates are in a custom cell format, and not a text string. Anyway to change the format within this code?

Comment: Just add `.Text` between the last 2 parenthesis in the first line with `str =` like this: `str = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cells(i, startCell.Column).Text)'